# Using -s command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a trivial error that I cant seem to get around. Im trying to return the various section numbers of lets say "man" since it resides in all the sections. I am using the -s command but am having problems. Every time I use it I keep getting "what manual page do you want". Any help?

Comment: Can you post the command you tried and the output you got?

Comment: fev@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ man -s man
What manual page do you want?

thats pretty much what i see

Comment: You're searching in the "man" section only instead of all of sections 1, 2, 3, etc., but what manual page are you wanting to view from the "man" section?

Comment: Its generic. What I am really after is the various section number like a tally of how many sections does the command reside. man is just the test case cuz i believe its in all the sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of getting the section number of a command, you want something like `man -k "page_name" | awk -F'-' "/^page_name \(/ {print $1}"`, replacing any occurrence of `page_name` with whatever command you're needing.

This won't work for all systems necessarily as the format for the "man" output is "implementation-defined". In other words, the format on FreeBSD, OS X, various flavours of Linux, etc. may not be the same. For example, mine is:

```
page_name (1)               - description
```

If you want the section number only, I'm sure there is something you can do such as saving the result of that line in a shell variable and use parameter expansion to remove the parentheses around the section number:

```
man -k "page_name" | awk -F'-' "/^page_name \(/ {print $1}" | while IFS= read sect ; do
    sect="${sect##*[(]}"
    sect="${sect%[)]*}"
    printf '%s\n' "$sect"
done
```

To get the number of sections a command appears in, add `| wc -l` at the end on the same line as the `done` keyword. For the `mount` command, I have 3:

```
2
2freebsd
8
```

Comment: Remember that `grep 'foo' | awk '{ bar }'` is better written `awk '/foo/ { bar }'`, though. In this case, `man -k | awk -F '[()]' '/^page_name \(/ { print $2 }'` might be closer to what you need.

Comment: I didn't use that variation only because a command may have spaces or parentheses in it. However, you're right about `/foo/`. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Spaces won't matter when you set the field separator to open or closing parenthesis.

Comment: True, but the command may contain parentheses. There are some odd programs in the wild... There may be additional information in the parentheses following the command name, such as the intended section contents (e.g. system commands, development, file formats, etc.), followed by another set of parentheses with the section. I don't make the output, and parsing it is error prone enough to make me find an alternate way if it won't be cross platform, unless I only need a system specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax requires an argument. Typically you're looking for either

```
man -s 1 man
```

to read the documentation for the [man(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man) command, or

```
man -s 7 man
```

to read about the [man(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/man) macro package.

If you want a list of standard sections, the former contains that. You may have additional sections installed locally, though. A directory listing of `/usr/local/share/man` might reveal additional sections, for example.

(Incidentally, `-s` is not a "command" in this context, it's an option.)

Answer (score 0):

You've misinterpreted the nature of `-s`. From `man man`:

> -S list, -s list, --sections=list
>
> List is a colon- or comma-separated list of `order specific' manual sections to search.  This option overrides the
>   $MANSECT environment variable.  (The -s
>                 spelling is for compatibility with System V.)

So when man sees `man -s man` it thinks you want to look for a page in section "man" (which most likely doesn't exist, since it is not a normal section), but you didn't say what page, so it asks:

> What manual page do you want?

BTW, wrt *"man is just the test case cuz i believe its in all the sections"* -- nope, it is probably only in one, and AFAIK there isn't any word with a page in all sections.  More than 2 or 3 would be very unusual.

The various standard sections are described in `man man` too.

Comment: Typically there's a `man` man page in section 1 (for the command) and in section 7 (for the macro package).